# Не получается обнулить текст в Input Field в Unity на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть *Input Field* для ввода названия проекта, мне нужно, чтобы текст в нем обнулялся по нажатию на кнопку "Отмена". Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение кажется простым, но я не могу его найти. Когда я открываю **GamePanel** и ввожу текст в *Input Field*, а потом нажимаю на кнопку "Отмена", то текст в *Input Field* остается тот, который я ввел.

Код

```
public Text GameNametext; //динамический текст в Input Field
public GameObject GamePanel, GameContentPanel; //GameContentPanel содержит в себе кнопки, которые будут доступны только после ввода названия игры.


private void Update()
{
    if(GameNametext.text == "")
    {
        GameContentPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        GameContentPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public void Closebttn() //метод для кнопки "Отмена"
{
    GameNametext.text = "";
    GamePanel.SetActive(false); 
}
```

Comment: попробуйте менять не компонент Text,а использовать currentInputField.text.

Comment: небольшое замечание по коду: все что в апдейте можно записать в одну строчку `GameContentPanel.SetActive(GameNametext.text != "");`

Comment: Кстати, вы для кнопки "отмена" не забыли обработчик в редакторе юнити привязать?

Comment: @trollingchar, в Unity все OK, я уже отдалился от такого типа ошибок) и спасибо за совет по сокращению кода

Comment: @Andrey, получается мне нужно объявить public InputField GameNametext, вместо public Text GameNametext ?

Comment: @dreamboy мне кажется что проблема в этом. Где то я уже видел подобное. Попробуйте, мне интересно

Comment: @Andrey, хорошо, сию же минуту, обождите

Comment: @Andrey, спасибо Вам большое! Все заработало, как часы, теперь буду иметь ввиду это, при работе с Input Field'ами. Не могли бы написать это в ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я описывал в комментарии проблема оказалась с тем что нужно было использовать InputField.

И  ещё уточнение. Лучше использовать ваш код не в `Update`, а

```
currentInputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(Method);

private void Method(string value)
{
   if(GameNametext.text == "")
   {
    GameContentPanel.SetActive(false);
   }
   else
   {
    GameContentPanel.SetActive(true);
   }
}
```

Тогда он будет проверяться не каждый кадр, а при изменении данных